# Android Vector Drawable - Hexagon shape with curved corners

Tags: android-vectordrawable

I want to create a hexagon shape in vector drawable. I was able to find something like this, except it does not have rounded corners.

```
<path android:name="hexagon"
    android:fillColor="#aa0000"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:strokeWidth="4"
    android:pathData="
    m723,314c-60,103.9 -120,207.8 -180,311.8 -120,0 -240,0
    -360,0C123,521.8 63,417.9 3,314 63,210.1 123,106.2
     183,2.2c120,0 240,0 360,0C603,106.2 663,210.1 723,314Z" />
```

Could you give me some hint how to create it like shown in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujHOg.png)?

I still try to learn how these curves works but I cannot figure it out.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Illustrator or [Inkspace](https://inkscape.org/) to convert your image into a **SVG** file.  Than upload the **SVG** file to [Shape Shifter](https://shapeshifter.design/) and the Shape Shifter will give you the Path and file to use for your Vector Image.

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="vector"
    android:width="160dp"
    android:height="160dp"
    android:viewportWidth="160"
    android:viewportHeight="160">
    <path
        android:name="hexagon"
        android:fillColor="#aa0000"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeWidth="4"
        android:pathData="M 45.856 145.287 C 42.844 143.796 39.144 141.246 37.635 139.621 C 32.787 134.403 7.938 90.337 6.681 84.732 C 4.518 75.078 6.223 70.935 26.735 36 C 41.676 10.554 41.433 10.667 81.344 10.667 C 121.707 10.667 119.656 9.431 141.095 46.671 C 155.423 71.56 157.469 77.508 154.645 86.066 C 153.736 88.819 147.283 101.031 140.304 113.203 C 119.796 148.969 121.578 147.93 80.667 147.97 C 53.825 147.996 50.868 147.768 45.856 145.287 Z"/>
</vector>
```